# Multiple argument in pthread_create

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

According to pthread_create man page, the argument of the function is:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                      void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

regarding the void `*arg`, I just wonder if I can pass multiple argument to it, because the function that I write requires 2 arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your `void*` you can pass a struct of your choosing:

```
struct my_args {
  int arg1;
  double arg2;
};
```

This effectively allows you to pass arbitrary arguments in. Your thread start routine can do nothing other than un-pack those to call the real thread start routine (which could in itself come from that struct).

Comment: Note that you **must** make sure the storage duration of the object passed is correct and that access to it is properly synchronized. For instance, if it's an automatic variable in the calling thread, then the calling function must not return until the new thread is finished accessing the data.

Comment: Using `malloc` and having the new thread `free` the object can be a lot easier and safer if you're not adept with synchronization.

Comment: @R - and you use a mt-safe malloc library.

Answer (score 1):

create a struct and rewrite your function to take only 1 arg and pass both args within the struct.

instead of

```
thread_start(int a, int b) {
```

use

```
typedef struct ts_args {
   int a;
   int b;
} ts_args;

thread_start(ts_args *args) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a structure and `malloc`. e.g.

```
struct 
{
   int x;
   int y;
   char str[10];
} args;

args_for_thread = malloc(sizeof(args));

args_for_thread->x = 5;

... etc
```

Then use `args_for_thread` as the `args` argument for `pthread_create` (use a cast from void* to args*). It is up to that thread to free the memory.

Comment: Don't forget to `free` allocated memory. Honestly I prefer allocation and de-allocation always within one function where possible.